# Magento 2 admin is not working after disable Magento_Theme

Tags: magento2

I made disable "Magento_Theme" module in (
Stores/Configuration/Advanced/Disable Modules Output), but after disabling I cannot see admin page (It's black page) and even storefront page, too. (Even I cannot see login page).. Is there anything I can do? (I think Magento is fail to set theme correctly when it load a page...).

I already tried to clear cache, all generation files...
Btw, this is Magento 2 store application.
Please help me..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling it from database table itself. In database Go to `core_config_data` table and search for value `advanced/modules_disable_output/Magento_Theme` in path column and set its value to 0.

**Suggestion:** You should not disable any core module directly, there are dependencies of modules.

Comment: There is no table named "core_config_data" in phpMyAdmin. Instead I found a table "authorization_rule". Is it also configurable table?

Comment: There must be a table with this name, it may have a prefix if you have added while installation. Hope you are checking in right database

Comment: I found it, and changed the value to 0 and cleaned all caches and generations. I think it works now, but it seems that loading js/css files failed. Should I apply Magento_Theme again? or Do I need to fix extra thing?

Comment: try to run compile command again and check

Comment: Thank you! At least it works for now except compiling issue. I created a new ticket for issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216444/magento-2-compile-failed-localizedexception-datapersistorinterface-does-not-exi . By the way, you saved my life!!

Answer (score 1):

Open `app/code/config.php` file and there search for 'Magento_Theme'. It would be set `Magento_Theme => 0`. change this to.

```
'Magento_Theme' => 1
```

After that clear cache, clear genration and then run `setup:upgrade` , `setup:di:compile` and `setup:static-content:deploy` command. hope it will work.

Comment: It was 1 even after I disable the module, I checked "bin/magento module:status" and "Magento_Theme" enabled. Should I re-compile again?

Comment: yes, you have to compile again, but make sure to delete fronted, adminhtml folders only in pub/static. and code in generation folder.

Comment: I tried to compile but there is another issue.. I created another ticket about the issue. Thank you anyway! https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216444/magento-2-compile-failed-localizedexception-datapersistorinterface-does-not-exi